# How exactly apoptosis starts?

Tags: biochemistry, cell-signaling, apoptosis

I read article about [apoptosis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apoptosis) on Wikipedia, but didn't understand, how exactly the organism learns that it is necessary to launch process of apoptosis in certain cell. In other words, on what signs the cell is marked as "necessary to destroy"? How exactly at the chemical/biological level process of apoptosis starts?
Also I am misled by the fact that apoptosis occurs by a row of strongly differing reasons - not only aging, functionality losing, chemical/radiation affection, but also process of apoptosis can start in absolutely normal cells (including just newly created ones - for example, during formation of an embryo). How in that case the embryo knows what cells need to be destroyed, and how exactly it does it?

Comment: Unfortunately, this question is far too broad. From the [help/dont-ask]: *`Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.`*

Comment: Too bad for me.

Comment: Maybe just evolution through chance-events and natural-selections helped them to adopt a self-destructive process? especially in multicellular forms?  For an example, in plants, xylem (made mostly of dead-cells) was obtained probably because the death of some water-conducting cells (hydromes, as yet seen in bryophytes), made them empty, thus deceased friction and adhesion, that was advantageous.